# Como fazer cache de uma requisção json xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, json, ios, xamarin-forms, httpclient

Gostaria de saber como fazer **cache** de uma requisição **HttpClient** cujo o retorno éum **json** e determinar a quantidade de dias de armazenamento desse cache.

```
public async Task<List<Categoria>> GetCategorias(){
        string URL = string.Format(Constants.apiURL, "ProdutoCategoria/Obter");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                  .Accept
                  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine(content);

        List<Categoria> listaCat = new List<Categoria>();

        try
        {
            var jsonRetorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Categoria>>(content);
            foreach (var item in jsonRetorno)
            {
                listaCat.Add(item);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("Ocorreu um erro: ", e.Message);            
        }
        return listaCat;
    }
```

Comment: Eu nunca usei diretamente nenhuma ferramenta para caching desse jeito. Nem sei se tem. A implementação de um cache também não parece ser lá um bicho-de-sete-cabeças... Só não ficou claro se o cache seria do lado do servidor ou do cliente.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza seria do lado cliente Diego.

Comment: @BrunoRichart, Qual a versão do .Net?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a versão é 2.1.301